# XPath to get sibling node's value

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm using a testing tool that generates XML like this

```
    <detail>
        <results>
            <component>A</component>
            <test>
                <property>performance</property>
                <result>FAIL</result>
            </test>
            <test>
                <property>memory</property>
                <result>PASS</result>
            </test>
        </results>

        <results>
            <component>B</component>
            <test>
                <property>files</property>
                <result>PASS</result>
            </test>
            <test>
                <property>handles</property>
                <result>FAIL</result>
            </test>
        </results>
    </detail>
```

Note that each *results* element contains 1 *component* element and 0-* *test* elements. I want to get the text of each *detail>results>component* and *detail>results>test>property* where a *detail>results>test>result* text is 'FAIL'.

Is there an XPath expression that would do this?

If not, is there a simple XSLT to transform the example into something I can import into a spreadsheet like

```
  A,performance,FAIL
  A,memory,PASS
  B,files,PASS
  B,handles,FAIL
```

Answer (score 5):

This Xpath will give you the properties that have failed:

```
//detail/results/test[result = 'FAIL']/property
```

And this will give you the names of the components that have a partial fail:

```
//detail/results[test/result = 'FAIL']/component
```

Combining these you can find all results that have a fail:

```
//detail/results[test/result = 'FAIL']
```

And then iterate inside this to get all failed tests in that result and returns the proprty that failed:

```
$result/test[result = 'FAIL']/property
```

I'm not on a machine where I can test an XSL yet, but putting one together from the above XPaths shouldn't be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

When the below transformations

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="detail">
    <xsl:for-each select="results">
<xsl:for-each select="test">
<xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::component"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="child::property"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="child::result"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

runs on below XML

```
<detail>
        <results>
            <component>A</component>
            <test>
                <property>performance</property>
                <result>FAIL</result>
            </test>
            <test>
                <property>memory</property>
                <result>PASS</result>
            </test>
        </results>

        <results>
            <component>B</component>
            <test>
                <property>files</property>
                <result>PASS</result>
            </test>
            <test>
                <property>handles</property>
                <result>FAIL</result>
            </test>
        </results>
</detail>
```

**gives the required Output:**

```
A,performance,FAIL
A,memory,PASS
B,files,PASS
B,handles,FAIL
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to prefer 'template match' and `apply-template` before for-each.

Therefor try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="detail">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="results[test/result='FAIL']/test" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="results/test">
        <xsl:value-of select="../component"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="property"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="result"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>  
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```